# Iterate included tuples in list more pythonic

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have this loop. Is there *smarter* way to this?

```
example = [('tes1', 'test2'), ('test3', 'test4')]
string = ''
for i, tuple in enumerate(example):
    string = string + ' '.join(tuple)
    if i != len(example) - 1:
        string += ', '
print(string)
```

I thinking about make it by .join(), but can't figure out how.

Comment: What is the intended vs actual output of your code?

Comment: It's works like intended, outputs `tes1 test2, test3 test4`

Comment: Why did you remove `string = ''`? It looks like your current code will produce an error.

Comment: Already do this

Comment: Also, I not checked when upload edit. It's not working code rn! (because of SCOPES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
example = [('tes1', 'test2', 'test'), ('test3', 'test4')]
string = ', '.join(' '.join(t) for t in example)
print(string)
```

No need for list comprehension; you can do with generator

Answer (score 3):

You could use an f-string in a list comprehension and then join the result

```
example = [('tes1', 'test2'), ('test3', 'test4')]
string = ', '.join(f'{x} {y}' for x, y in example)
```

Comment: One problem with this solution - it's only it only takes two values in a tuple.

Comment: @TheVorkMan Was there anything in your question that might lead to thinking that the tuples could be comprised of more than one item? Given your sample data, this is a very good answer

Comment: I don't understand you a little. This is a good answer to this question. But still - in this answer tuples not iterate - this is not what I need and what is indicated in the code that was attached.
(google translated, I'm sorry for misunderstanding)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it using the following:

```
string = ', '.join([' '.join(t) for t in example])
```

Answer (score 1):

With joins, you could express it like:

```py
example = [('tes1', 'test2'), ('test3', 'test4')]
string = ', '.join(map(' '.join, example))
print(string)
```

Comment: Second good answer